# How to read the data from one excel sheet based the other sheet in the same workbook usig webriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have created a workbook into which I have created two worksheet, In first sheet I have given three attributes test case ID, Description, and Execution flag to True or False based on this flag test case will execute and In another sheet I have given the test case steps and test data from all the tests and also I have given the id to each test case based on this id I want to access the data from sheet one which is I have declared in sheet one also.. please tell me how can I do this in selenium webdriver using java

Thanks in Advance

Comment: read the excel and then with the data work with the webdriver

Comment: Sorry, but [tag:webdriver] cannot read Excel. You will have to use some other library, like [tag:apache-poi]. Show us what you tried so far, perhaps we could help you out.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you must be using the JXL api for getting data and storing it in a variable

If you are doing that

Read the data from the sheet 1 
store it in a variable
then use

the condition

if (val1==true)
{
  Start reading the data from the other sheet

}

Else

{

END YOUR EXECUTION 
}

Link for the jxl reader is below
http://startingwithseleniumwebdriver.blogspot.in/2014/03/excel-reading-with-jexcel-api.html